# i am using navigationDrawerFragment for google map but my googlemap attribute is showing null

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3, nullpointerexception

i am using google map api for google map, map is coming to fragment but whenever i tried to create an instance of map but my google map variable is showing null.

```
//this is my class extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MapView mapView;
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.location, container, false);
    if (map == null) 
    {
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.googlemapfragment1);

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(mapView!=null)
        {
            map = mapView.getMap();
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        }
        if(map!=null)
        {
            Log.e("not null","not null");
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

xml file is like this

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/googlemapfragment1"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the newly introduced method to get map in async manner.Try using

```
SupportMapFragment mapView = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemapfragment1);
mapView .getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
        map = arg0;
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

please update your google play services if you are unable to see that method.

Comment: add this import "import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;"

Comment: (SupportMapFragment) view.findViewById(R.id.googlemapfragment1); shows view cannot be cast to supportmapfragment

Comment: (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemapfragment1);

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() not coming

Comment: you  told that your class extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment. If that is the case, you should be able to getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: i used like this     final SupportMapFragment mapView= (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemapfragment1);    but still its giving null pointer exception

Comment: Instead of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), use getChildFragmentManager(). Hope it helps.

Comment: still its giving null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75356/discussion-between-dora-and-rah).